# Can I visit a city in the US during layover if my port of entry was a different city?

Tags: layovers

I have an Indian passport and a B1/B2 US Visa and I am travelling to California.

While returning, my flight is via Dallas. Can I exit the Dallas airport on landing there and go through immigration again to catch my flight back to India?

Comment: @k2moo4: Doesn't look like a duplicate at all to me (except to the extent that "yes, that's okay" is an answer to them both).

Answer (score 6):

Sure.

The US does not have exit immigration so you won't go through immigration in Dallas on your return flight no matter what you do. But when your flight from California to Dallas lands, you can follow the signs to the exits and leave. When you return to the airport, you'll go through TSA airport security and make your way to your gate.

Note that the airport is a fair distance from downtown, and you'll need to be back at the airport with enough time to go through security and get to your gate in time for boarding (long-haul flights start boarding quite some time before departure time), so this is really only an option if you have a particularly long layover in Dallas.